# How can I download and read a URL with universal newlines?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, urllib, python-2.7

I was using `urllib.urlopen` with Python 2.7, but I need to process the downloaded HTML document and its contained newlines (within a `<pre>` element).

The [urllib docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) indicates urlopen will not use universal newlines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the HTML file is already on your disk, `urlopen()` will handle correctly all formats of newlines (`\n`, `\r\n` and `\r`) in the HTML file you want to parse (that is it will convert them to `\n`), according to the [urllib docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

> "If the URL does not have a scheme identifier, or if it has file: as its scheme identifier, this opens a local file (without universal newlines)"

E.g.

```
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> urlopen("http://****.com/win_new_lines.htm").read()
'line 1\nline 2\n\n\nline 3'
>>> urlopen("http://****.com/unix_new_lines.htm").read()   
'line 1\nline 2\n\n\nline 3'
```

Comment: You're right. After further diagnosing my bug, I realized this was not actually the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you process the contents of the `pre` tags, use [splitlines](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to normalize the line-endings:

```
'\n'.join(contents.splitlines())
```