# how to validate csv upload form in django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-forms

I am trying to validate a csv file upload in django with the following:

```
class CSVUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(label='Select a CSV file to import:',)

    def clean(self):
        print 'clean'
        file_csv = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        records = csv.reader(file_csv, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        for row in records:
            print ', '.join(row)
```

I get the error:

```
new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

I thought the dialect took care of this.

If I change the reader to open with the rU flag, it works:

```
records = csv.reader(open('/mylocalpath/'+file_csv.name, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

The problem is that since this file is streamed, the actual file is totally different than this local one.

How can I pass the rU flag to the streamed/uploaded version of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Three different approaches:

1. Some files aren't written to file when uploaded, depending on the file upload size (FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is 2.5 mB by default). So if you want to re-open the file using that flag, you could write the file to disk first.
2. Another possibility is setting FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to 0 and inspecting the object linking to the upload file, you should be able to get the filename and then re-open it using the special flag.
3. Use `splitlines()` as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315921/58107).