# error when reading lines from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to get an idea of some lines in a huge csv file so I did this

```
with open('###.csv','rb')` as csvfile:
    conusreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in conusreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

Then I got an error in Pycharm

> "for row in conusreader:
>   _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?"

I'm not quite sure what it means.
Could anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Could you gave a small example of your csv file?

Comment: The error is implying you need to try using something like this: `csv.reader(open(csvfile, 'rU'), delimeter=' ', quote='|')`. Which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: Hi Martin. I use OS X Yosemite and IDE is Pycharm. a line of the file looks like this (geospatial data) "GA 13215 Muscogee County 1 Columbus -84.8769 32.51 250 -85.0262 32.608 -85.0228 32.6079 -85.0216 32.6079 -85.0154 32.6078 -84.9818 .......".

Comment: I tried what you wrote and got the same error...

Comment: Do you get any output or does this fail on the first loop? Consider loading the file into an editor to try and spot what is triggering the fault. Consider using a hex editor to spot 0x0D 0x0A characters in the csv file.

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error