# How to Sort a Column in an Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, sorting

So I understand how sorting works in Python. If I put...

```
a = (["alpha2A", "hotel2A", "bravo2C", "alpha2B", "tango3B", "alpha3A", "zulu.A1", "foxtrot8F", "zulu.B1"]
a.sort()
print a
```

I will get...

```
'alpha2A', 'alpha2B', 'alpha3A', 'bravo2C', 'foxtrot8F', 'hotel2A',  'tango3B', 'zulu.A1', 'zulu.B1']
```

However, I want to sort a column in a Excel sheet so I tried...

```
isv = open("case_name.csv", "w+")
a = (["case_name.csv"[2]])
a.sort()
print a
```

And got a return of...

```
['s']
```

I understand that it is returning the 3rd letter in the file name but how do I make it sort and return the entire column of the Excel sheet?

## Update: New Code

```
import csv
import operator

with open('case_name.csv') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))

data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))

with open('case_name_sorted.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(data)

print(sum(1 for row in data if len(row) < 3))
```

And it returns

```
data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Comment: If you could save the excel file as a `.csv` file, then your life becomes significantly easier. Is this a possibility for you?

Comment: Yes it is already a csv file, but thanks.

Comment: Change the body of your first `with` block to `data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))`. That would be a good start

Comment: okay I updated the code and the return

Comment: We are now back at an earlier error, for which I pointed you to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17315635/198633)

Comment: ahhh, ok I see that farther down they talk about how csv does not work. So what kind of file should I use then? Should I change it to xlsm?

Comment: And now, we're out of my field of expertise. I'm sorry I won't be able to help out further, but I'd much rather not give you incorrect information.

Comment: That's fine, you have done more than enough already! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import oprator

# read the data from the source file
with open('case_name.csv') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect='excel'))

# sort a list of sublists by the item in index 2
data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))


# time to write the results into a file
with open('case_name_sorted.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect='excel'))
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to  open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: Ack! that sounds like an issue with the excel dialect. As I don't usually work with excel files, I have never faced this issue before. However, I would recommend reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17315635/198633)

Comment: ok I did that but now it says...IndexError: list index out of range. What line was I supposed to have changed?

Comment: That error makes me think that you have at least one row that has fewer than 3 columns

Comment: All of the rows have three columns in total and I am only trying to sort the last column, everything is filled in. There are no empty cells.

Comment: What does `print(sum(1 for row in in data if len(row) < 3))` print?

Comment: I put what my code looks like now as an answer, and the code you just told me to add does not print anything for some reason.

Comment: Firstly, please edit your original post with the new code, etc. To address your problem, you haven't posted the error you get, or any output. I would recommend that you fix the indentation in your new code, and also use `infile` within the first `with` statement