# python syntax error after adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am readying a cvs file,

this is my code:

```
import csv
class CsvToJson:
    def __init__(self, csvFilePath):
        with open(csvFilePath, 'rb') as csvFile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= ‘;’, quotechar = '|')
            for row in spamreader:
                print ', '.join(row)

k = CsvToJson(csvFilePath = 'carsModelsMakes.csv')
```

I got this error

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file CsvToJson.py on line 7, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

on the fifth line.

I read on internet and it seems the solution is to use

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the beginning of the file.

I did that but then i got this error:

```
File "CsvToJson.py", line 6
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= ‘;’, quotechar = '|')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

could you help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
delimiter= ‘;’,
```

You need straight quotes, not smart quotes:

```
delimiter= ';',
```

Comment: now i am getting this error   File "CsvToJson.py", line 10, in <module>
    k = CsvToJson(csvFilePath = 'carsModelsMakes.csv')
  File "CsvToJson.py", line 7, in __init__
    for row in spamreader:
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error

Comment: i tried to check the solution there, they say to change my rb to rU, but then i got a new error which is  File "CsvToJson.py", line 5
    with open(csvFilePath, 'r’) as csvFile:
                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
Williams-MacBook-Pro:ExcelToJson williamkinaan$ python CsvToJson.py 
  File "CsvToJson.py", line 5
    with open(csvFilePath, 'rU’) as csvFile:
                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You'll have to indicate the correct dialect that was used to create your CSV file. If it was created manually, without a specific dialect, you'll have to fix it manually, adhering to a specific dialect. A program like Excel may be able to help you there.

Comment: what is that `dialect` ? please . i tried to re save it using microsoft office on my mac os and still the same problem

Comment: As an argument to the `csv.reader()` call, as seen in the linked answer.