# csv.Error: new-line character

Tags: python, numpy

I am using some sample code (below) to test a NB classifier and Im getting the following error from line 22:

```
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

This is a sample row of the csv file:

```
b8:27:eb:38:72:a7,df598b5eb8f4,5/9/16 14:47,154aec250ef6,-84,outside
```

sample of code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn import naive_bayes
import csv
import random
from sklearn import metrics
import urllib
url = "example.com"
webpage = urllib.urlopen(url)
# download the file
#raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)

datareader = csv.reader(webpage) #line 22 is this one

ct = 0;
for row in datareader:
  ct = ct+1
webpage = urllib.urlopen(url)
datareader = csv.reader(webpage)
data = np.array(-1*np.ones((ct,6),float),object);
k=0;
for row in datareader:
    data[k,:] = np.array(row)
    k = k+1;

featnames = np.array(['unti','dongle','timestamp','tracker','rssi','label'],str)

keys = [[]]*np.size(data,1)
numdata = -1*np.ones_like(data);

for k in range(np.size(data,1)):
    keys[k],garbage,numdata[:k] = np.unique(data[:,k],True,True)

numrows = np.size(numdata,0);
numcols = np.size(numdata,1);
numdata = np.array(numdata, int)
xdata = numdata[:,:-1]
ydata = numdata[:,-1]

lbin = LabelBinarizer();
for k in range(np.size(xdata,1)):
 if k==0:
   xdata_ml = lbin.fit_transform(xdata[:,k]);
 else:
   xdata_ml = np.hstack((xdata_ml,lbin.fit_transform(xdata[:,k])))
ydata_ml = lbin.fit_transform(ydata)


allIDX = np.arrange(numrows);
random.shuffle(allIDX);
holdout_number = numrows/10;
testIDX = allIDX[0:holdout_number];
trainIDX = allIDX[holdout_number:];

xtest = xdata_ml[testIDX,:];
xtrain = xdata_ml[trainIDX,:];
ytest = ydata[testIDX];
ytrain = ydata[trainIDX];

mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB();
mnb.fit(xtrain,ytrain);
print "Classification accuracy of MNB =", mnb.score(xtest,ytest)
```

Can anyone help me find the error and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows? If yes, this can be solved by:

```
datareader = csv.reader(webpage, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

Comment: hm.. weird.. did you tried adding the `dialect` kwarg?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here [CSV new-line character seen in unquoted field error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error) refer to CSV in MAC

Can you try to manually download the file to your MAC and try to do the following with the file as local file:

1) Save the file as CSV (MS-DOS Comma-Separated)

2) Save the file as CSV (Windows Comma-Separated)

3) Run the following script

```
with open(csv_filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

explanation about 'ru': https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/

In a Python with universal newline support open() the mode parameter can also be "U", meaning "open for input as a text file with universal newline interpretation". Mode "rU" is also allowed, for symmetry with "rb"

**Rationale**

Universal newline support is implemented in C, not in Python.
This is done because we want files with a foreign newline
convention to be import-able, so a Python Lib directory can be
shared over a remote file system connection, or between *MacPython
and Unix-Python on Mac OS X*