# csv file sorting rows by columns in python without pandas

Tags: python, sorting, row

My lessons with python continues and im stuck with this exercise where i have such csv:

```
John^Reporter^Angola
Mary^Engineer^Canada
Anna^Manager^India
```

and would like to achieve this:

```
Angola^John^Reporter
Canada^Engineer^Mary
Anna^India^Manager
```

so every row is sorted by content in column from left to right.

I tried with this code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as sortrow:
    reader = csv.reader(sortrow.readlines(), delimiter='^')
    reader = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x[0])
    with open(syspath+temppath+'/added5.csv', 'w') as sortwrite:
        writer = csv.writer(sortwrite, delimiter='^')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

i thought sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x[0]) will do the job but its not.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `reader = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x[0])`, your key is the first column (`x[0]`).

In your case you don't want to sort the rows but the columns, so

1) don't sort the reader

2) just do this:

```
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(sorted(row))
```

full fixed code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'rU') as sortrow:
    reader = csv.reader(sortrow, delimiter='^')  # don't use readlines()
    with open(syspath+temppath+'/added5.csv', 'w', newline='') as sortwrite:
        writer = csv.writer(sortwrite, delimiter='^')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(sorted(row))  # sort done here
```

note that if there was a consistency between the data of the same columns, it is lost by the column sort

Comment: so this line  `reader = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x[2])` is always sorting columns? then how to sort every row from left to right?

Comment: 'for row in reader:
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?'

Comment: ok, try `open('file.csv', 'rU')` and tell me (I don't have your file) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error)