# How to access raw csv content in universal-newline mode using DictReader?

Tags: python, reader

I have these lines of code:

```
>>> import csv, io
>>> raw_csv = io.StringIO('one,two,three\r1,2,3\r,1,2,3')
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(raw_csv, delimiter=',')
>>> list(reader)
```

which results the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.9/csv.py", line 110, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File ".../lib/python3.9/csv.py", line 97, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

I found [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error?rq=1) using with `open()` but I cannot use it since there is no file path. I also need to use `DictReader`.

Comment: Why does the string use `\r` instead of `\n`? This isn't really valid CSV any way you slice it. Did you actually mean for it to contain a header line and two data lines? What does the `with open` solution look like?

Comment: I saw \r is an old Macintosh convention: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

Comment: The with open() solutions by using newline='' 
I added the link in the quesion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `newline=''` to the [`StringIO` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to enable universal newline mode:

```
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(file), delimiter=',')
>>> next(reader)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 110, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 97, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

>>> reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(file, newline=''), delimiter=',')
>>> next(reader)
{'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
```

Comment: The `csv` module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) say to open files with `newline=''`, it's nice to know that `StringIO` supports that.

Comment: Of course, with a static string, you could populate it with `\n` instead of `\r` in the first place, or (somewhat more expensively) `StringIO(file.replace('\r', '\n'))`

Comment: @tripleee Of course, but I assume that the static string was only for the sake of making a minimal example :)